# Symfony 3 register with roles as CollectionType (FOSUserBundle)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony and I am trying to create a registration form with the capability to choose a user role.

I used the official documentation to set this up: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html

But I got the following error:
[image: this screen]

My RegistrationType is :

```html
<?php

namespace DevLeaguesBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
  $builder->add('roles', CollectionType::class, array(
                   'type' => 'choice',
                   'options' => array(
                       'choices' => array(
                           'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin',
                       )
                   )
      ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'devleagues_user_registration';
    }

 public function getName()
 {
  return $this->getBlockPrefix();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ChoiceType Field http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

```
$builder->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
                       'choices' => array(
                           'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin',
                      )
                   )
);
```

Comment: I tried this earlier to but it seems that i must have something wrong somewhere since now i get a new error : Notice: Array to string conversion
Thx anyhow

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this notice comes from this line?

Comment: for now, this code is commented and no bug appears anywhere. What do you think it could come from?